# c# vista - how to implement color scheme in code? framework 2.0

Tags: c#, windows-vista, color-scheme

I have an application which I run on vista. when i tried to change the color scheme of windows (right click on desktop ->personalize->window color and appearance -> change color scheme to high contrast black) I cannot see the text and background images I use.

any idea what to do?

Comment: Please, don't say HELP PLEASE.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using the Label control to display text, if you have set an explicit color in the ForeColor property, for example setting it to Black from ControlText, then it would no longer follow the selected Windows color scheme.